# Center fixed width/liquid css layout with display: table attribute and min/max widths

Tags: css, layout

The goal is to center this layout on the screen. I have a min-width of 600px and max-width of 1200px, so there is potentially a lot of white space around the layout.

I've been trying lots of different methods, but am confused about the display:table attribute and how it behaves in this scenario.

Here is the jsFiddle and code: http://jsfiddle.net/7M9rg/6/

Thanks so much for any advice on this!

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="main">

<div id="side">
<div id="side-stuff">
<ul>
<li><a href="../English/index.html">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">&copy; 2013 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*css reset*/
html,body {position:relative;margin:0;padding:0;min-height:100%;width:100%;
height:100%;}
div,p,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,
textarea,p,blockquote,th,td, figure {margin:0;padding:0;}
ol,ul {list-style:none;}
li {list-style-type: none;}
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing:
border-box; }


html, body {
font-family: Helvetica;
height: 100%; /*important for equal height columns*/
min-width: 650px;
}

#wrapper{
height: 100%; /*important for equal height columns*/
padding-bottom:130px; /*This must equal the height of your header*/}

#header{
height: 130px; /*This must equal padding bottom of wrap*/
display:block;
padding: 5px;
color: #fff;
border: thin solid #ebebeb;
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 10px;
background-image: url(Images/gradient.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;    
width: 99%;}

#main {
position: relative;
height: 100%; /*important for equal height columns*/
width: 99%;
overflow:auto;
display: table; /* This is needed fo children elements using display table cell*/
table-layout: fixed;
padding-bottom: 50px; /*This needs to match footer height*/
overflow: auto;
margin-left: 10px;}

#side{
background-color: #fff;
width: 150px;
margin: 10px;
vertical-align: top;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-right: 10px;
display: table-cell;
border-radius: 10px;
border: thin solid #CCC;}

#side-stuff{
display: block;
padding-left: 10px;}

#content{
background-color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
display: table-cell; /*To make sibling columns equal in height*/
margin-bottom:10px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: thin solid #CCC;}

#content-stuff{
width: auto;
height: auto;}

#footer{
position: relative;
height: 40px;
margin-top: -40px; /* margin-top is negative value of height */
margin-left: 10px;
clear: both; /* Use if floating elements */
color: #999;
width: 99%;
border: thin solid #ebebeb;
border-radius: 10px;
background-image: url(Images/footer_gradient.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: bottom;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your #wrapper CSS:

```
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tshz6/

Comment: Thanks so much for replying. Yes, I did this first, but for me it didn't work. I'm stumped that it seems to work in jsFiddle, but not when I test it in a browser.  Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify width for your `<body>` or `#wrapper` element. `min-width` only specifies the *minimum* width it can be shrunk to, and `width` and `max-width` is set to `auto`, which is all available width (in this case the screen width).
Try updating your `html, body` rule to following

```
html, body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 650px;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I have already tried setting the margin as specified in your example, but that does not do it for some reason. I'm not sure I understand your comment about specifying width (which I would not be able to do with a semi liquid layout); should I do anything else?

Comment: `I have a min-width of 600px and max-width of 1200px, so there is potentially a lot of white space around the layout.` if i understood this correctly, you want your page's width  between `650px and 1200px` depending upon the user's screen resolution. The CSS in the answer sets the `max-width` so that it doesn't get wider than `1200px` and `margin: 0 auto` centers it. Try this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7M9rg/8/

Comment: BTW, by `Try updating your html, body rule to following` i meant replace the `html, body` rule that comes after the _reset rules_

Comment: Ejay, I'm so sorry, for some reason the max-width didn't make it into the code, but I did have it there all along. I did add the margin: 0 auto; but it's still not centering for me. I did another jsFiddle and it's not working there either, so something in the code must have changed that is now interfering. Would you mind taking a look? http://jsfiddle.net/eJyD2/ Thanks!!!

Comment: you've a missing `;` after `color:#333` that's preventing `margin: 0 auto` from taking effect

Comment: I got it. I was missing a semi colon after color attribute in the html, body section. Shame on me. It's working fine now. Thank you very much to my two helpers! I appreciate you taking the time.